# Sharing a variable between javascript and VB .net in webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, vb.net, variables, sharing

I have a VB.Net form application with a webbrowser control. I have created a HTML5 page as a string and load it in the webbrowser as documenttext. This works very well. Now if the user interacts with the page (which is actually a chart using D3), like drag an item, I have that changed javascript variable and I wish to transfer it to some form of storage from which VB .Net can fetch it when VB.Net attempts to reload the page next time.

Cookies and localstorage does not work in this situation as the page is running from a local filesystem and not a server. The javascript in the page will then give an undefined or null reference error.

I do not wish to transfer the variable to a remote mysql server and fetch it back as it slows it down. I am seeking any solution that is executed locally.

Comment: You are removing a lot of options here. I don't understand how can you run vb if it's not on a server, even a local IIS. The only way I can see is if you do an ajax call to the vb.net file and send your variable as a post/get. Then the vb would save it in a local file, which could be argued might end up being worst than calling a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after some researching. It can be done by setting the ObjectForScripting property of the webbrowser control. This will expose the windows form class to the javascript on the html page. You have to set the permission of the class to make it visible to COM. Then the JavaScript can call any function or object in the class using window.external object.

[You could see the implementation in the following page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx)

[A very detailed explanation can be found in this page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35373/VB-NET-C-and-JavaScript-communication)